# How to customize the modern SharePoint online list toolbar?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-list, sharepoint-2019

[image: Toolbar]

How to customize the modern SharePoint online list toolbar?

I was not able to find any options that were available in previous versions in SP. I have an option under the "...", toolbar and I want to add it to the toolbar. Also, want to remove the share, export, automate and integrate options from the toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

To customize the modern SharePoint online list menu bar, you have to build a Sharepoint Framework(SPFx) extension.

Reference:

[Overview of SharePoint Framework Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/overview-extensions)

[Build your first SharePoint Framework Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/build-a-hello-world-extension)

Demos:

[How To Hide Command Bar Menu Item Using SPFx Extension](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-hide-command-bar-menu-item-using-spfx-extension/)

[react-application-injectcss](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-extensions/tree/main/samples/react-application-injectcss)

[Inject Custom CSS on SharePoint Modern Pages using SPFx Extensions](https://tahoeninjas.blog/2018/05/08/inject-custom-css-on-sharepoint-modern-pages-using-spfx-extensions/)